# Cutting surface beyond the box, using persp in r

Tags: r, plot

I have created a nice surface in r using the persp function.

```
persp(Xseq, Yseq, matrix, theta=30, phi=30, ltheta=30, scale=F, axes=F)
```

Now I would like to see the lower level sets of my function. That is, I want to sketch the surface for z < 1, for example. When I add zlim to the persp function as follows

```
persp(Xseq, Yseq, matrix, theta=30, phi=30, ltheta=30, scale=F, axes=F, zlim=range(0,1))
```

The problem is that, it still draws the whole surface, and gives an error saying that **surface extends beyond the box**.

Although I can change Xseq, Yseq to a smaller set in order to achieve z<1, is there an easy way to plot the surface restricted in the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities.  The simplest is to set the values in `matrix` to `NA` when you don't want to plot them.  For example,

```
Xseq <- Yseq <- (-10):10
matrix <- outer(Xseq, Yseq, function(x,y) (x^2+y^2)/10)
persp(Xseq, Yseq, matrix, theta=30, phi=30, ltheta=30, scale=F, axes=F)
```

gives this with no limits on Z:
[image: screenshot]

and if I only want Z<1, I can do this:

```
lowvals <- matrix
lowvals[lowvals > 1] <- NA
persp(Xseq, Yseq, lowvals, theta=30, phi=30, ltheta=30, scale=F, axes=F)
```

[image: screenshot]

The other possibility is to use `rgl`.  I generally prefer solid surfaces to mesh surfaces, but in the example below I've drawn both.  To avoid artifacts of disappearing grid lines I need the `polygon_offset` argument in the first version:

```
library(rgl)
persp3d(Xseq, Yseq, matrix, col = "green", axes = FALSE, zlim = c(0,1),
        xlab = "", ylab = "", zlab = "", polygon_offset = 1)
persp3d(Xseq, Yseq, matrix, front="lines", back = "lines", zlim = c(0,1),
        lit = FALSE, add = TRUE)
aspect3d("iso")
box3d()
```

[image: screenshot]

The advantage of `rgl` is that you can rotate the surface to get the best view more easily than trying to set the view in `persp`, and you have more flexibility about what is drawn.  The disadvantage is that you might have trouble incorporating the result into a document:  you would use `rglwidget()` to get rotatable HTML output, `rgl.snapshot()` to get a bitmapped image.  (There's also `rgl.postscript()`, which sometimes does a better job than `rgl.snapshot()`, but doesn't support all images; I'd avoid it.)